# Java Select from database with where condition

Tags: java, mysql

I have a question. In my method

```
public void  selectUser(String name, String surname)
```

I try to log user. How I can prepare an sql statment like this one:

```
String sql = "select * from user where surname= (here my surname from method parameter) and name= (name from method parameter)  ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Inialize your `PreparedStatement` object

```
PreparedStatement pst = null;
pst = c.prepareStatement("select * from user where surname= ? and name= ? ");
            pst.setString(1, getterMethodHere);
            pst.setString(2, getterMethodHere);
```

`1,2` represents the `surname= ? and name= ?` symbol respectively

[Learn More . .](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

San Krish thanks. Now how to use rs.next because i don;t understand prepareStatemnt.

Here's the code

```
enter code here  



        //stat = con.createStatement();
        //String sql = "select * from user where surname= "+surname+" and name="+name;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from user where surname= ? and name= ? ");
        pst.setString(1, name);
        pst.setString(2, surname);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();



        while (rs.next()) {
            //get from column name

            String id = rs.getString("id");
            String login = rs.getString("login");
            String password = rs.getString("password");

            //print

            System.out.print(" id: " + id);
            System.out.print(", login: " + login);
            System.out.println(", pass: " + password);
        }
```

and how to return id ?

Comment: iterating the resultset is same as before . you are doing it in the right way

Comment: So why I can't see my id,login and pass ?